# How do you configure Rubocop to display rule when running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

It seems like, instead of the SUPER helpful Offense/Concern/Warning sytax like:

```
C: Use delete instead of gsub.
```

It could display:

```
C: Use delete instead of gsub. Cop name: [Whatever it's upset about]
```

So you could disable the thing without another hour of googling the ungooglable.

I've googled this for a while now and have yet to find the answer in the 4,200 questions this excellent linter has generated.

Answer (score 2):

To display the cop name in the output, you can use `--display-cop-names`, or `-D` for short.

Example:

```
$ bundle exec rubocop -D tmp.rb
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

tmp.rb:1:6: C: Style/MethodCallParentheses: Do not use parentheses for method calls with no arguments.
hello()
     ^
```

Answer (score -1):

```
be rubocop --dedbug
```

That sort of does it... you can toss a file name in there as well

```
be rubocop app/models/ihaterubocop.rb --dedbug
```

Comment: that would be debug not dedbug. Is your question how to fix the offense or how to turn off the warning?